# Keep a variable in content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'd like to keep number of rows in db in my content provider.

```
private int nRows;
public int getNRows(){
   return nRows;
}
```

The idea would be to initialize this variable in the onOpen() method and the just increment/decrement it in insert/delete methods, is this correct?

As content provider's life cycle is handled by android I fear that it could delete my private variable at some point...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean `onCreate()`, not `onOpen()`?
If so - it will be correct, if you'll renew this variable

1. In onCreate() - maybe requesting current count from underlying structure/db
2. After each insert/delete operation

If you'll do above - so you'll have no problems, as it's guaranteed that `onCreate` will be called before any other provider's methods, and even if system will kill the provider - you'll restore this value in next instance's `onCreate()`

**Note:** That all applies only if any changes to DB can be made only through this provider. Else - you should request data count each time, or cache on other level.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks I just wanted to be sure about variable's consistency! :D

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Cursor#getCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) method to get the number of rows instead of keeping track manually.